# How to get current contract id when exercising choice

Tags: daml

How can I get the contract id when exercising a choice since this refers to the current contract but not the contract id?

I can not find it through DAML SDK.

Answer (score 1):

In a non-consuming choice there is an implicit variable `self` that provides the contract-id of the current contract. This is similar to the implicit variable `this` that provides the contract *contents* within a choice.

The current DAML semantics specify that a contract is archived at the beginning of a consuming choice, so even if you had access to `self` in a consuming choice, there is nothing you could do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit `self` variable is actually visible within all choices, non-consuming or otherwise. As pointed out though, currently it's of no value in a consuming choice because the behavior of a consuming choice is that the contract instance on which the choice is exercised is archived before execution of the choice body (that is, the semantics are "pre-consuming"). In a future release the set of choice annotations will expand to include `preconsuming` and `postconsuming`. In a post-consuming choice, the contract referred to by `self` will remain active throughout the choice body and be archived at the end. A choice not annotated with `preconsuming`, `noconsuming` or `postconsuming` will default to the pre-consuming semantics (just as it is today).